# How to update "wpLoadPhp" setting for CiviCRM WordPress when moving/migrating installation?

Tags: wordpress, settings, multisite, migration

On my Civi WordPress multisite installation, I just discovered that there is a `wpLoadPhp` setting in the CiviCRM settings *for each Civi domain* that contains the absolute filesystem path to `wp-load.php` (for example: `/home/myusername/sites/mydomain.org/wp-load.php`). So this setting needs to be updated if I move WordPress+Civi to a new location, or move a copy of the Civi database to a development or test installation.

I discovered this setting when the Civi `cv` CLI tool misbehaved—it tried to load settings from the wrong WordPress installation for a `cv api setting.create ...` command. (However, using the WP-CLI  `wp cv api setting.create ...` worked correctly. It must override the Civi `wpLoadPhp` setting.)

What is the correct/best way to update the `wpLoadPhp` setting—preferably via a script for automation? Is `wp cv api setting.create ...` best? It seems to work OK: e.g. `wp cv api setting.create wpLoadPhp=/home/myusername/sites/mydomain.org/wp-load.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore this setting unless you're hitting scripts in `civicrm/extern` or `civicrm/bin` or using `cv` directly. In that case I'd recommend switching to routes that go via WordPress e.g. the REST API or `wp cv` instead - they are much more reliable in WordPress.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I'll stick with `wp cv` whenever I can... but I think I can only use `cv` for `api4` right now.

Comment: Yes, that's true. API v3 still has greater coverage though. FYI the `wpLoadPhp` setting was introduced because it is impossible for plugins to know where WordPress is located. So you're right - use `wp cv` to update `wpLoadPhp` then you should be able to use `cv` for API v4.